# Creating log-in form in C# with MySQL server (principal issue)?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, authentication

I have a Log in form in C# Winforms with a sign-in button (as shown in the screenshot). I want on button click to check if a user with the given name  do exist. I do it with the following piece of code (i submit only the necessary code):

Provided that the second field in my `users` table in the database is `username` so assuming the `IsDBNull()` has an argument 1 (if we count from 0) I would like to ask what am I doing wrong because there is such a user, i.e the field is not null but the second form that I want to show does not want to open. I would like to ask why is that?

[login screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78aFD.jpg)

Comment: Change `*` to be the **specific** column you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL is on a web server (Even XAMPP) I would recommend outputting the information through PHP. This also leaves it open to comparing passwords for logins and such via the webRequest library. I would not recommend using this code in final release, but instead I would recommend using it for testing and building off of.

For the code to work you will need a few things:

- A web server of any sort, XAMPP is good for testing locally as it comes with Apache and phpMyAdmin
- An SQL database with at the bare minimum a section named username with one item inputted into it

After that, simply add the following code, update the link in the var webRequest section of the C# code and go from there!

At the top of your C# you will need to include: using System.Net;

C# loginButton_onClick

```
// Connects to the website
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://yourwebsite.com/programLogin.php?username=" + textBox1.Text);
using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
{
    // This gets all of the info given out by the website
var info = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Comparing to expected outputs
    if (info == "User found in the database")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username Exists", "Login Form");
    }
    else if (info == "Username not found")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username Not Found", "Login Form");
    }
    else
    {
        // This will most likely only thow if the website is down OR if there is a HTTP error 500 OR unsuccessful login to the database
        MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error", "Login Form");
    }
}
```

programLogin.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$user = $_GET['username'];

if (isset($user))
{
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            // $row['username']; will show the informaiton from the database;
            echo "User found in the database";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username not found";
    }
}
?>
```

If this doesn't answer your question, toss me some more information on what is needed for your program and I will get back to you with some more help/resources!

**This code is not tested**

Edit: Added the using that is required